# SharePoint 2007 to SharePoint 2010 Migration Plans

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, migration, sharepoint-2010

Our company had a difficult time migrating from WSS 2003 to MOSS 2007 and we're starting to plan out our approach for migrating from MOSS 2007 to MOSS 2010.  Does anyone have any plan/strategy for upgrading existing SharePoint 2007 sites to SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to the [SharePoint 2010 upgrade center](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee517214.aspx) on TechNet. This will be your best starting point.

Some highlights you'll need to keep in mind:

- SharePoint 2010 is 64-bit only and only runs on Server 2008. If your 2007 farm isn't 2008 64-bit you are talking about a rebuild of your farm
- SharePoint 2010 requires 64-bit SQL Server, so you are also possibly talking about a rebuild of your SQL environment
- If you do need to do the 64-bit/2008 migration, Microsoft has a [guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd622865.aspx) for upgrading to a new 64-bit 2007 farm, then you can do an in-place upgrade of that to 2010
- SharePoint 2007 (and WSS) SP2 contains a pre-upgrade checker for SharePoint 2010 - you can run that and it will help assess your readiness for a 2010 upgrade
- Other than that, the options are very similar - In Place upgrade or DB Attach - there are some cool new things though. With DB attach, you can attach multiple DBs at once and they will be upgraded in parallel.
- Although you upgrade the SharePoint bits, you can leave your sites in "2007" mode and change them to the 2010 look/feel on a site-by-site basis.